# Is there a trick to the 'Find something quests?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Would it be to find a dog tag or frogs, I seem to be missing something in the 'go find something for me' quests.

I go to the area, and then run in circles for half an hour to find the prompt to pickup.

Am I doing the quest right? Or is there some ability that makes it easier to find the quest item? (Something like asking your party to look for the thing instead of tagging along with me whining that its cold and rainy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Frog quests: Listen carefully. The Frogs croak if you are near them (the louder they are the closer you are)

For The Dogtags: I ran into the middle of the targetcircle and started looking for an encounter. after that the i could find then near the fight in a smaller circle (The tags always had a yellowish shine instead of blue for items)

Comment: Good tip about the frogs! Could have saved me lots of time. You got any tips for finding the stones though? Those are the hardest, I wasted over full hour (real time) on the last one I had (Reliable Royalty) and gave up. I don't want to look in YouTube, it's cheating.

Comment: Sorry i just ran around in the Circle until i found them.

Comment: And for others, like the traps, it's just running around until the prompt shows up

Comment: The traps are visible but hidden under leaves and gras.